# How does sponge (from moreutils) work?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stdout, stdin

sponge can “soak up” stdin and write it atomically to a file, enabling one to do `cat f|sponge a`. I want to know how exactly it accomplishes this. How does it know when the input is finished?

Comment: What do you mean? The same way every other program knows (e.g. `cat f | wc` or `cat f | grep foo` or whatever), why would you expect `sponge` to be special?

Comment: https://git.joeyh.name/index.cgi/moreutils.git/tree/sponge.c

Comment: I think the OP means `cat f| sponge -a`, not `cat f|sponge a`. In other words, how can it write to same file that's being read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strace` or similar will show the system calls used by `sponge`, which is probably to [`write(2)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man2/write.2) the input [`read(2)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man2/read.2) from standard input out to a temporary file, and then to [`rename(2)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man2/rename.2) that temporary file to the desired output filename when the input ends. The input ends when a `read(2)` call fails or returns `0` (which indicates end-of-file) at which point `sponge` can do the rename.

Comment: And when the `rename()` fails with EXDEV when `/tmp` is on a different file system, it ends up copying the data again into the destination file. You can avoid that by setting `TMPDIR` to `$(dirname target-file)` or use `ksh93`'s `>;` operator instead of `sponge` which does that automatically (and also doesn't override the target file if the redirected command failed).

Comment: `>;` ? mind blown.